# Sum of two 4-bit and a 5-bit number with 74181 ALU any advice?

Tags: alu

I was designing a medium logic circuit and when trying to figure out this equation with 74181 ALU, I couldn't really find anything about how to make this work with a 4 bit ALU.

equation F= 2A + B while A is 4 bit binary number, B is a 5bit binary number.

I tried use another 74LS83 to do sum but I think there is a short way, any help?

Comment: Tolgaocal, can you at least discuss your thoughts about the equation? This smacks of a homework question, as it is very easy to answer yet also requires just a small bit of thinking. In short, this looks like the very kind of question I might ask a student just to see if they understand the material. If they don't, the problem will look very hard. But if they do understand it, then they will see right through the question and answer it in short order. So what's your thinking? Do you have any thoughts at all about the problem beyond what you wrote?

Comment: Assuming this is school work, then you are not supposed to "find anything" about how this works. Then this isn't a test of your searching skills on the internet. Instead, this is about your ability to creatively use your own thinking processes in combination with your education (whether well-taught or not) to achieve a result when faced with something slightly novel. This requires nothing more than one 74181. I'll clue you in that much.

Comment: Here is a hint, the lowest bit of \$2A\$ is zero. Now think.

Comment: Another hint, the lowest bit of $F$ is exactly the same as the lowest bit of $B$ and the lowest bit of $B$ has no impact on the remaining bits of $F$.

Comment: okey I get it now, this wasn't my homework also, thanks prof. you are all the same. @copper.hat thank you, I understand with that clue.